# How to get the slider to move back to its original position if a tab is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This code (located here http://jsfiddle.net/Svvift/Lhcaeboz/2/ and also inserted below) works perfectly to make an animated navigation bar. My only wish now is to have the slider return to its original position if a tab isn't selected. Currently, it still just sits there regardless of selection or not.

HTML

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="red" class="item"></div>
<div id="blue" class="item"></div>
<div id="yellow" class="item"></div>
<div id="green" class="item"></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#red {
    background-color:#FF0000;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

#blue {
    background-color:#0000FF;
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
}

#yellow {
    background-color:#E2BE22;
    height:100px;
    width:50px;
}

#green {
    background-color:#008800;
    height:100px;
    width:170px;
}
#slider{
    background-color:#6FF;
    height:10px;
    width:100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

SCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#slider").animate({
          "left": $(".item:first").position().left + "px",
          "width": $(".item:first").width() + "px"
        }, 0);

    $(".item").hover(function(){
       $("#slider").stop(); $("#slider").animate({"left":$(this).position().left+"px","width":$(this).width()+"px"},500);
    });
});
```

This is what I tried

```
$("#slider").delay(3000).animate({
    "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
    "width": $(this).width() + "px"
}, 500);
```

Comment: you need to have teh code in the question... not just a jsfiddle link

Comment: I apologise for making some of it code when it didn't need to be but for some silly reason it wouldn't let me post it unless I did that.

Comment: Don 't post _only_ a link to a jsFiddle in your question. You've gotten that warning message for a reason! Post your ___code___ in the question. Don't circumvent this block by formatting text as code.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I made the update

Comment: @Cerbrus I made the update

Comment: @nathanchere I tried this code

Comment: $("#slider").delay(3000).animate({
    "left": $(this).position().left + "px",
    "width": $(this).width() + "px"
}, 500);

Comment: Don't worry the legend @avi solved it!

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhcaeboz/3/)?

```
 $(".item").on( "mouseout",function(){
       $("#slider").stop(); 
       $("#slider").animate({"left":$('#red').position().left+"px","width":$('#red').width()+"px"},500);
    });
```

Comment: Yes! @avi THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will select your answer as the winning answer in seven minutes coz stackoverflow told me to wait

Comment: no worries, glad to help.

Comment: Wait its not working on my website! Oh no!@avi

Comment: It works in JSfiddle but not on my website

Comment: maybe you have different id's for the div's with .item class?

Comment: No I figured out the issue but I don't know how to fix it. Your code is good but the only issue is when you look at this JSFiddle I made ( http://jsfiddle.net/helpmuchappreciated/Lym2wLLb/6/ ) it works when you hover in the button div but as soon as you hover over the text it stops and screws up the animation. It is because the text in the button is in a separate div. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: You'll see what I mean if you hover just under the text still in the div it works, as soon as the cursor touches the text, YIKES!

Comment: Let me know if you know what I mean @avi

Comment: Add  pointer-events: none; to your .inside class. It should fix the problem.

Comment: I don't have a .inside class?

Comment: Yes, you do. The divs containing the text have class='inside'. Check the css in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lym2wLLb/7/

Comment: sorry forgot to tag you in the last comment

Comment: Oh my goodness! I am so sorry @avi ! I must be going blind. You were right, I apologise. Haha. Thank you, I thought I was losing my mind. Haha. LOL! Thank you so much you're a legend. I will favourite your answer now

Comment: TADA! Done. You have now earned the points for answering my question that I just ticked for you! :) You deserved it!

Comment: Hey @avi I was wondering if you could please help me with this question since you helped me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197291/unanswered-positioning-this-div-is-a-nightmare-please-assist